# How to perform Multivariate binary logistic regression in R

Tags: r, statistics, logistic-regression, glm

How can I perform a multivariate binary (logistic, probit..) model in R ?
I've a set of Y (y1, y2,..., yp) response variables which are binaries.

I tried `glm` function in R but I can't fit multivariate (set of many variables as response in one model)

I tried `glmer` function in lme4 package. But it allows only two response variables (y1, y2).

Comment: I've already tried it, but it doesn't work

Comment: Can't mark as a duplicate on a sister site, but this is [asked and answered at stats.stackexchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/26585/7515). Summarized: fit a separate model for each response variable.

Comment: @GregorThomas I find this answer on many sites. But fitting separate models can't solve my problem. I aim the multivariate analysis like manova or canonical discriminant analysis for continuous variables.

Comment: Maybe look into the package `brms`? It's very flexible